# SQLite SELECT gives exception How to fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, exception, select

I am developing an android application (using Eclipse and 5554 emulator). When I execute the following code it seems CREATE TABLE and INSERT is working correctly but SELECT has some problem.

Do you think the problem is coming from CREATE TABLE and INSERT? or Is syntax of SELECT not right?

```
public void onCreateA(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        System.out.println("On create works");

        try {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS actuator;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actuator ("+
                    "ACTUATOR_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,"+
                    "ACTUATOR_HW_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "DEVICE_NAME TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "DEVICE_TYPE TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "DEVICE_SUB_TYPE TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "LOCATION_ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "MAX_STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "MIN_STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                    "PRIMARY KEY (`ACTUATOR_ID`))");

            System.out.println("table created now values will be added");

            System.out.print("DONE!");


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("table is not created");
        }

        try {
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO actuator (ACTUATOR_ID, ACTUATOR_HW_ID, DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_TYPE, DEVICE_SUB_TYPE, LOCATION_ID, STATUES_VALUE, MAX_STATUES_VALUE, MIN_STATUES_VALUE) " +
                    "VALUES (1, 2, 'Heat Sensor FX615','Heat Sensor', 'Optic Heat Sensor', 4, 6, 7, 8) " );
            System.out.println("values are added");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("values are not added");
        }

        try {
            db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM actuator");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("not selected");
        }


    }
```

but the output is :

```
04-11 08:49:24.513: I/System.out(1499): **On create works** 
04-11 08:49:24.571: I/System.out(1499): **table created now values will be added** 
04-11 08:49:24.627: I/System.out(1499): **DONE!values are added** 
04-11 08:49:24.513: I/System.out(1499): **On create works** 
04-11 08:49:24.631: W/System.err(1499): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only. 
04-11 08:49:24.631: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
04-11 08:49:24.631: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at com.example.databasetryout.DataBaseTryOut.onCreateA(DataBaseTryOut.java:196) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at com.example.databasetryout.DataBaseTryOut$3.onClick(DataBaseTryOut.java:75) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
04-11 08:49:24.641: W/System.err(1499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
04-11 08:49:24.651: W/System.err(1499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-11 08:49:24.651: I/System.out(1499): **not selected** 
04-11 08:49:24.651: I/System.out(1499): **finish**
```

Comment: -1 for not reading a stacktrace/logcat logs and documentation ... `SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only` ... anyway even for INSERT you should not using `execSQL`

Comment: try use executeQuery or something like that.. 
read here http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/16410-sqlite-pragma.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM actuator");
```

You can't use `execSQL` method for statements which return data. Exactly from docs

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.

You have to use [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery) or [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query) method.

So for your case, you can use following snippet of code for getting data from database:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM actuator";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Actually, your code do nothing. If you want to retrieve data from db, you need to assign them to Cursor via methods mentioned above.

Comment: thanks dude. I had no idea about "cursor". Now it is working perfect sorry for not voting up due to insufficient reputation to vote lol.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your log, the error is: Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.

So, in android, you have to use SQLiteDatabase or rawQuery.
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Example:

```
rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name = ? AND id = ?", new String[] {"David", "2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM actuator");
```

You are trying to execute a `SELECT` query with `execSQL` method, however this is a query that returns results, and hence must be run using a relevant method.  In your case, you can do this with `rawQuery` method:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM actuator", null);
```

It's worth noting thought that this code is pointless, it does nothing apart from running the query in the database.  You won't see any results because you are not even assigning the results to a variable.